# Redis is thread safe , so why use `BlockingConnectionPool` in redis-py

Tags: python, django, redis

I use Django cache.I know Redis is thead-safe.

If `BlockingConnectionPool` is necessary, when I configure `CACHE`.

What does `BlockingConnectionPool` do?

When I need use `BlockingConnectionPool`?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/issues/341).

Comment: Thanks. But if i use default connection pool, is it will be thread safe?

Comment: `Redis` itself is thread-safe no matter which connection pool do you use.

Comment: Thanks,I think  that `BlockingConnectionPool` is only used for limiting max connections to redis. Every thread has a redis connection to redis. If no more available connections then this thread blocks until a connection becomes available (a thread release a connect).   Is it correct?

Comment: It is. Fill more characters.

Comment: Thanks.  what does "Fill more characters." mean. I am a newbie in stackoverflow.

Comment: It means you should type at least 15 characters to post a comment. "It is" is too short.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I understand. I think that BlockingConnectionPool is only used for limiting max connections to redis. Every thread has a redis connection to redis. If no more available connections then this thread blocks until a connection becomes available (a thread release a connect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BlockingConnectionPool`  is a class in redis. Despite that Rdis is thread safe `BlockingConnectionPool` increases the reusabity.
It performs the same function as the default :`py:class: ~redis.connection.ConnectionPool` implementation, in that, it maintains a pool of reusable connections that can be shared by multiple redis clients (safely across threads if required).

For more description visit this link:
https://kite.com/python/docs/redis.BlockingConnectionPool

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official docs](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) The "Blocking" in `BlockingConnectionPool` is not a reference to *thread-safety*, but rather to the fact that if there's no connection available this implementation will wait (*block*) for a specified number of seconds (`timeout` param) until one becomes available.

```
# Raises ConnectionError if connection is not available within before 10s timeout
pool = BlockingConnectionPool(timeout=10)
```

Specifying `timeout=None` will block indefinitely.